# Python setting a variable, string becomes unicode

Tags: python, json, unicode

I'm trying to iterate through some json and add the keys to a db. I have a function that returns a string. When I assign that string to a variable, the variable prints a unicode string. Why?

```
json_obj = json.loads(data)
for resource in json_obj:

    # returns a string
    san_resource = self.sanitize_resource(resource)

    fresource = FertilityResource.objects.get_or_create(
        title = san_resource['Resource Name'],
    )

    print(fresource[0].title, san_resource['Resource Name'])

def sanitize_resource(self, *args):
    ''' return resource values as string or blank string '''
    resource = {}
    for key, value in args[0].iteritems():
        resource[key] = str(value).strip() if value != 'None' else ''
    return resource
```

So I assign `san_resource['Resource Name']` which is a string to `fresource[0].title` and when I print that, it's *sometimes* unicode. Example output from the print statement above:

```
('Atrium Family YMCA', 'Atrium Family YMCA')
('Auburn Valley YMCA', 'Auburn Valley YMCA')
(u'Shop Well With You', 'Shop Well With You')
(u'Look Good Feel Better', 'Look Good Feel Better')
('Abba Wig Salon', 'Abba Wig Salon')
```

As you can see, `san_resource['Resource Name']` is always a string and `fresource[0].title` is a string, but sometimes unicode. Why is this? How can I fix it?

Comment: What does `sanitize_resource()` do?

Comment: Does this even matter? What operation are you performing on this data that requires that no unicode strings are present?

Comment: why does it matter if its unicode sometimes? @Two-BitAlchemist ... jinx

Comment: serialized json is always unicode so all if the strings in `json_obj` will be unicode. I have no idea what `sanitize_resource` does, but if it uses any of the strings from `json_obj` without converting them to strings, you'll get unicode. If you "sanitize" the strings by building ascii strings (`str(some_json_string)`), you run the disk that it is not ascii and cant be decoded.

Comment: when I pass title to get_or_create, it doesn't create anything if the u is in front of the string

Comment: I really don't understand why it's sometimes unicode and not all or none of the time. how is it even getting converted?

Comment: `get_or_create()` returns `str` or `unicode` here. `json` has nothing to do with it. `san_resource['Resource Name']` is always `str` in your code.

Answer (score 1):

> When I assign that string to a variable, the variable prints a unicode string

It's when you pass that string to the function `get_or_create()`:

```
fresource = FertilityResource.objects.get_or_create(
    title = san_resource['Resource Name'],
)
```

If a `FertilityResource` exists in the database with a primary key matching this (presumably `title`), you get the existing `FertilityResource` instead returned from the database. In this case, `title` will be a Unicode string because all Django ORM `CharField` properties are natively `unicode`.

On the other hand if you don't have an existing instance in the db, Django creates a new instance with the exact values you give it. It doesn't bother fetch the instance back out of the database after putting it in, so you get left with the untouched `str`.

```
resource[key] = str(value).strip() if value != 'None' else ''
```

What's this for? It will fail for non-ASCII characters in `value`. You should try to keep all your strings in `unicode` form, it's the normal way of working with text and the native type for both JSON strings and Django character fields. Maybe you want something like:

```
# Convert non-string types to strings
if not isinstance(value, basestring):
    value = unicode(value, 'utf-8', 'replace')
# Ignore special null value
if value == u'None':
    value = u''
resource[key] = value.strip()
```